# Modifying Magento frontend tabs to custom view : For bundled products

Tags: xml, magento

I want to show additional details of sub products in case of bundled products.

So i did below thing to add additional detail in bundled products.
I have used the below XML code in admin "custom layout update"

```
<catalog_product_view>
 <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>description</alias>
        <title>Description</title>
        <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
        <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>additional</alias>
        <title>Additional</title>
        <block>core/template</block>
        <template>mourtabs/bundledtabs.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag">
            <alias>tags</alias>
            <title>Tags</title>
            <block>tag/product_list</block>
            <template>tag/list.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
            <alias>review</alias>
            <title>Reviews</title>
            <block>review/product_view_list</block>
            <template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template>
        </action>
 </block>
</catalog_product_view>
```

But I can not see any changes.

But when I remove **"catalog_product_view"** from above code i.e using the below code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>description</alias>
        <title>Description</title>
        <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
        <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
        <alias>additional</alias>
        <title>Additional</title>
        <block>core/template</block>
        <template>mourtabs/bundledtabs.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag">
            <alias>tags</alias>
            <title>Tags</title>
            <block>tag/product_list</block>
            <template>tag/list.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
            <alias>review</alias>
            <title>Reviews</title>
            <block>review/product_view_list</block>
            <template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template>
        </action>
</block>
```

I am able to see "Additional" details in magento frontend tabs, but on product listing page I see the below fatal error:

```
Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in 

D:\wamp\www\myfolder\app\code\core\Mage\Review\Block\Product\View\List.php on line 40
```

Please guide me to a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

error is of review block. Review block call for particular product. When you open any product detail page, product_id will set into object but there object is null so getId() error. Make sure u are passing product_id to block for that page.